# Time difference using strtotime

Tags: php

This shouldn't be hard, but still I don't understand what is happening.

```
<?php
    echo date( 'H:i', strtotime( '09:00' ) - strtotime( '08:00' ) ); 
    // returns 02:00 instead of 01:00

    echo date( 'H:i', strtotime( '18:45' ) - strtotime( '17:15' ) ); 
    // returns 02:30 instead of 01:30

    echo date( 'H:i', strtotime( '17:00' ) - strtotime( '09:00' ) );
    // returns 09:00 instead of 08:00
```

### What is adding the extra hour?

So maybe I need to add a date?

```
<?php
    echo date( 'H:i', strtotime( '22-09-2016 17:00:00' ) - strtotime( '22-09-2016 09:00:00' ) );
    // still 09:00 instead of 08:00
```

### Some extra information

I am using Laravel en tested in Xampp.

In Laravel /config/app.php `'timezone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',`

In Xampp `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');`

Still no difference.

<strike>This calculation is done in the blade template where I cannot access the DateTime class.</strike>

I found a way to use the DateTime class. Another solution was changing the timezone to `UTC`, but then all my other timestamps are wrong.

Comment: is this a timezone issue?

Comment: `date` functions are using the locale of your server to determine the time zone. This is why you should be using `DateTime` class and its friend, `DateTimeZone`. Manually handling the timestamp is a bit obsolete way of handling date information.

Comment: @Mjh you should set this as an answer. Possibly with an example.

Comment: `strtotime` seems entirely inappropriate here. You only need a time difference so you don't need any fussing around with the Unix timestamp which strtotime does.

Comment: The reason why there's an hour added is because of daylight savings time. The date is converted to UTC (because of `strtotime`). Then, the difference is calculated (1 hour). However, the `date` will spit back something else because DST adds 1 hour at the moment. So, instead of 1 hour, you get 2 hour diff. That's what happens and that happens because `date` uses server's time zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

find difference using DateTime object like

```
$time1 = new DateTime('18:45');
$time2 = new DateTime('17:15');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I');
```

Answer (score 2):

As a purely variety alternative to the method posted by [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635423/3536236), because you're looking at only *time* values rather than date values you don't need the [slight] overhead that `strtotime` generates by converting everything to unix timestamps. you also don't need to worry about time zones, as it's a purely mathematical operation.

```
function minutes_from_time($time){
    $parts = explode(":",$time);
    $minutes = ($parts[0] * 60) + $parts[1];
    return $minutes;
}

$timeLapsed = minutes_from_time("09:00") - minutes_from_time("08:00");

/***
 Format into H:i
 ***/
 $hours = floor($timeLapsed/60);
 $minutes = $timeLapsed - ($hours * 60);
 $minutes = sprintf("%02d", $minutes); //force 2 digit minutes.
 $hours = sprintf("%02d",  $hours); //force 2 digit hours.

 $result = $hours.":".$minutes;
```

You may need to handle some special cases of times crossing over midnight, but....

If in the future you do want to include dates and/or time zone data then definitely go with using the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) as recommended by myself and others.

Comment: A great answer! After searching, I found a way to use the DateTime class. That's why I accepted the other answer.

Comment: I was surprised to read Blade doesn't implement DateTime. Glad you got it fixed `:-D` . DateTime *is* the way to do it best, @RonvanderHeijden

Comment: That's why I have been looking further to be able to use the class in blade :D

Answer (score 1):

Problem with timezones.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 0); //return "1970-01-01 01:00:00";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 3601); //return "1970-01-01 02:00:01";
```

use `DateTime::diff` for correct work